# how to calculate and plot the fast fourier transform of sla data (3 d matrix) in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, fft, netcdf

I want to check for the existent dominant peaks in sla data(3 d matrix lon, lat ,time) from which I can delineate what period to choose so that I can filter this data and look for waves propagating in the region. My data is for all lat and lon(global data). However, I want to average over a lon range of 70E to 100E and after that average over 10S to 10N. This average will give a a vector only in time dimension over which I can perform fast fourier transform. Then I want to plot this with time as the x axis. I'm new to matlab, any help is appreciated. Also if anyone has done this before it would be nice if you told  me if my logic is correct or not.

Comment: Hi Trishneeta, I'm keen to help, but your explanation is a bit difficult to follow. Could you write out your plan in a series of bullet points, i.e. 1) do this, 2) do that, 3) do some more. Also, I don't know whether your data being sla data is relevant: it looks like the data just has 2 spatial dimensions and 1 time dimension. Once you average over the 2 spatial dimensions, you should only have a single dimension (time) remaining.

Comment: Thanks so much Michael for your comment. I'll enumerate things.

Comment: 1.) I have sla data with two spatial and one time dim. (you are right in that). 2.) I want to average over longitude 70E to 100E and latitude extent 5S to 5N. 3.) This will give me sla data points only on time axis. This I want to plot so that I can see the peak of sla at specific time periods. These periods of peak will give me the time period over which to use butterworth filter. 4.) How can I use indexing in matlab so that I can average over my required lat and lon extent?     Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: So the question is about how to average over a specified section of your array. I'm going to assume your EW and NS grids are uniformly spaced with spacing `dew` and `dns`, i.e. `EW = -180 : dew : 180; NS = -180 : dns : 180;`. You need to find the indices that satisfy your averaging criterion, i.e. `ilon = (EW >= 70) & (EW <= 100); ilat = (NS >= -10) & (NS <= 10);`. Then `data(ilon, ilat, :)` will only contain the time series in the region of interest. Finally, to average: `mean(data(ilon, ilat, :), [1, 2]);` or `mean(mean(data(ilon,ilat,:), 1), 2);` if you're on an older version of MATLAB.

Comment: Matlab version in 16b. My data is an nc file with grid as 0.125E to 0.125W points being 1440mr. And 89.875S to 89.875N with points being 720r. So when I tries the EW and NS >= those commands did not work. I tried ilat=(lat >=-10) & (lat <=10); same with ilon. Then mean_sla=mean(sla(ilat,ilon,:),[1,2]); I'm getting this error.  Error using sum
Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

Error in mean (line 116)
        y = sum(x, dim, flag)/size(x,dim);

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Please isolate the mathematical/coding problem from the application. I don't understand what an nc file is, or what 1440mr is supposed to mean. Also please surround your code snippets using the backtick symbol (` symbol is ~ without SHIFT on most keyboards) for better formatting.

Comment: Okay. I'm new to coding so please bear with me. I'll try to make things clearer. 
The grid of my data goes from 0.125E to 0.125W in steps of 0.25 and from 89.875S to 89.875N in steps of 0.25. Because of this the commands NS>= something is not working. 
I tried `ilat=(lat >=-10) & (lat <=10);% same with ilon` Then trying to do mean I tried
` mean_sla=mean(sla(ilat,ilon,:),[1,2])`
I am getting the error message as follows:  Error using sum Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.
 Error in mean (line 116) y = sum(x, dim, flag)/size(x,dim);

Comment: In my previous comment, I gave 2 ways to compute the mean. Use the other method.

Comment: In this case the indexing method is not working. The command ilon = (EW >= 70) & (EW <= 100); is not recognised. Probably because the EW notation is not recognised.